# How to fix this validation? C#

Tags: c#, validation, binary, decimal

Ok so, I've made a basic binary converter into decimal, and I'm trying to validate the users input, so that it can only be a 0 or a 1, this works fine the first time, If they type an incorrect value it asks them to re-enter it, but the problem occurs if they type an incorrect value the 2nd time around, how would I happen to fix this? or like loop it back to a specific part of the program? Thanks a lot, here is my code:

```
if (iBinaryNum1 == 1 || iBinaryNum1 == 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("The binary value entered for integer 1 is correct");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("The binary value entered for integer 1 is incorrect");
  Console.WriteLine("Please Re-enter this value");
  iBinaryNum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: Is it easier if you don't do read line and get ket presses one at a time instead? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is actually quite simple, not sure if you've found a solution yet, but the best way to carry out this validation would just be to remove the if else statements all together and use a while loop like followed:

```
while (iBinaryNum1 < 0 || iBinaryNum1 > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value entered was incorrect");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Re-enter this value: ");
            iBinaryNum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

This will just continuously prompt the user to re-enter the value until they get it correct

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I would suggest using a loop. For example (in pseudocode)

```
bool validValue = false;
while(!validValue)
{
  // Get input from the user
  // Print a message and set validValue
  // As soon as you set validValue to false the loop will break
}

// Your value will be valid here.
```

Also, please be careful with `Convert.ToInt32` - it throws an exception if you enter an invalid value. You can have a look at `int.TryParse` instead.

Comment: Surely you meant to use a do while :)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Surely not. This template is valid.

Comment: Any loop structure will do, really. You just have to be careful in cases like these, that you don't want to print the "Your input is invalid" message before the first entry (e.g. `do { if(invalid) { printMessage(); } getInput(); }`). I always prefer the variation where the input code (`ReadValue()`) is not duplicated right above or below the loop, as in the other answer.

Comment: @BartoszKP, a while is for when you want to execute the code 0 or more times, a do while when it's 1 or more. They want to execute it 1 or more so it's a do while that should be used. By using a while you're say there's a possibly that it might not be execute but that isn't the case.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko If you want to say that you can use `do`...`while` for this then you're right. The rest of what you write is your opinion, which I respect, but it's nothing more. I find `while` loops more readable, and in this answer it is clear that the code will execute at least once. Feel free to post your idea as an answer - it presents a valid alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
  iBinaryNum1 = ReadValue();
  iBinaryNum2 = ReadValue();

  while (!(iBinaryNum1 == 1 || iBinaryNum1 == 0))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("The binary value entered for integer 1 is correct");
    iBinaryNum1 = ReadValue();
    iBinaryNum2 = ReadValue();
  }
```

You have to mote the reading into a separate function to be able to call it repeatedly. Then put a while loop that won't accept continuing until correct values are entered.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a do while loop

```
    do {
    if (iBinaryNum1 == 1 || iBinaryNum1 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The binary value entered for integer 1 is correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The binary value entered for integer 1 is incorrect");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Re-enter this value");
        iBinaryNum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
} while (iBinaryNum1 ! = 999);
```

if you type in 999 or some exit value it'll exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Windows Forms / WPF application, you can probably restrict your user to input only valid values, by applying restrictions on the input control such as TextBox, NumericUpDown or MaskedTextBox etc.